# How to efficiently query MongoDB for documents when I know that 95% are not used

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

I have a collection of ~500M documents.
Every time when I execute a query, I receive one or more documents from this collection. Let's say I have a counter for each document, and I increase this counter by 1 whenever this document is returned from the query. After a few months of running the system in production, I discover that the counter of only 5% of the documents is greater than 0 (zero). Meaning, 95% of the documents are not used.

My question is: Is there an efficient way to arrange these documents to speedup the query execution time, based on the fact that 95% of the documents are not used?

What is the best practice in this case?

If - for example - I will add another boolean field for each document named "consumed" and index this field. Can I improve the query execution time somehow?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the data?  Ideally, you might even be able to add appropriate indices on existing columns right now.

Comment: Of course indexs are good in this situation, without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, which may be much slower

Comment: I am aware of indexes and how to use them. My question is how to use the fact that more than 95% of my data is actually "garbage" to speed up the result. (No. I cannot delete the "garbage" since I don't know what is "garbage" and what is not). Only after a few months of real production work, I will know what documents are used. And sure, it may happen that an unused document become used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~500M documents` That is quite a solid figure, good job if that's true. So here is how I see the solution of the problem:

1. If you want to re-write/re-factor and rebuild the DB of an app. You could use versioning pattern.

How does it looks like?

Imagine you have a two collections (or even two databases, if you are using micro service architecture)

Relevant docs / Irrelevant docs.

Basically you could use find only on `relevant` docs collection (which store 5% of your useful docs) and if there is nothing, then use `Irrelevant.find()`. This pattern will allows you to store old/historical data. And manage it via [`TTL index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) or [`capped collection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/).

You could also add some Redis magic to it. (Which uses precisely the same logic), take a look:
[image: prototype]

[This article](https://epsagon.com/development/using-redis-to-optimize-mongodb-queries/) can also be helpful (as many others, like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218941/architecture-for-redis-cache-mongo-for-persistence))

But don't try to replace Mongo with Redis, team them up instead.

2. Using `Indexes` and `.explain()`

> If - for example - I will add another boolean field for each document named "consumed" and index this field. Can I improve the query execution time somehow?

Yes, it will deal with your problem. To take a look, [download MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), create this `boolean` field in your schema, (don't forget to add default value), index the field and then use `Explain` module with some query. But don't forget about [`compound` indexes!](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) If you create field on one index, measure the performance by queering only this one field.

The result should been looks like this:
[image: Index useage]

If your index have usage (and actually speed-up) Compass will shows you it.

To measure the performance of the queries (with and without indexing), use `Explain` tab.

> *Actually, all this part can be done without Compass itself, via `.explain` and `.index` queries. But Compass got better visuals of this process, so it's better to use it. Especially since he becomes absolutely free for all.*